# Add Control in rCharts::Highchart in R

Tags: r, filter, rcharts

I'd like to use this: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5548_c3b680696b084e5db17eecf8c079a3c1.html

but I need list filter like this: http://rcharts.io/icontrols/#.Vbs9WZP1GlM

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you expand on your question to pinpoint exactly what you're after. Are you looking to develop a shiny app to apply filters to plot only a subset of the data?

Comment: I need to do markdown report. I want to put on plot X-axis 2 values per month on barplot and add filter like in this example: http://rcharts.io/icontrols/#.Vbtam5P1GlN

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'filter'.